# Part of speech of "one half" in "one half a number plus three is five"

Tags: quantifiers

I thought it should be "one half of a number" but it seems one half a number" is the preferred way of saying this. Why? Is it incorrect to use "of" here?

Does the same apply to an actual number such as "one half 8 is 4"?

Comment: Why do you think "half [a number]" is 'preferred'?

Comment: Right. I find many instances of "twice a number" and "three times a number" on popular Math websites and textbooks.